# Issue with Gas Prices on Transactions with Web3

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js, ganache

I am creating an application where a user will be able to send tokens from their wallet to another wallet. The wallets are created at the time of user registration with web3js' `eth.accounts.create` function. However, the balance is 0 in all of them and I can't send tokens. I tried sending ether from Ganache test wallets but still no use. Here's the function `sendToken`:

```
let data = req.body;
  const txData = {
    to: data.rcv_address,
    value: web3.utils.toWei(data.value.toString(), "ether"),
    gas: 21000,
  };
  web3.eth.accounts
    .signTransaction(txData, data.snd_key)
    .then((signedTx) => {
      const signedTransaction = signedTx.rawTransaction;
      // Proceed to broadcast the signedTransaction
      console.log(signedTx);
      web3.eth
        .getBalance(data.rcv_address)
        .then((balance) => console.log("BALANCE:", balance));
      web3.eth
        .sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction)
        .on("transactionHash", (txHash) => {
          console.log("Transaction Hash:", txHash);
          web3.eth
            .getTransactionReceipt(txHash)
            .then((receipt) => {
              if (receipt && receipt.blockNumber) {
                console.log("Transaction confirmed!");
                // Update balances
              } else {
                console.log(
                  "Transaction not yet confirmed. Retry after some time."
                );
              }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error("Failed to get transaction receipt:", error);
            });
        })
        .on("error", (error) => {
          console.error("Failed to broadcast transaction:", error);
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Failed to sign transaction:", error);
    });
```

This is the payload that I am sending:

```
{
    "snd_address": "0xfd0C541706cFD1C6C3fDFdfA84a9d0785afA91e3",
    "rcv_address": "0x731Ba15C9304846cB55f36F376a4b8F8d223Ba1b",
    "snd_key": "0x0b0da575dbe003503d8ef2355beefd698332c67f07f4f3d3b5bb9f9db07b898c",
    "value": 1
}
```

When I am sending from Ganache Test Wallet, the transaction goes through but the balance of receiving address is still 0 and I can't broadcast the signed transaction:

```
  messageHash: '0x953f74adcb7fb008ca30a5e31adaae67cf4285f5e3582e34f1005735b22647a9',
  v: '0x25',
  r: '0x308b12255560c80bcfb50756a9f21c9af11b50ff33676dce67b3d93c00243546',
  s: '0x5c084b41900fe1d229c1fe62998ad81d384b917b43dc9ddcf3a840bb3d820e84',
  rawTransaction: '0xf86d8085059105471282520894731ba15c9304846cb55f36f376a4b8f8d223ba1b8902b5e3af16b18800008025a0308b12255560c80bcfb50756a9f21c9af11b50ff33676dce67b3d93c00243546a05c084b41900fe1d229c1fe62998ad81d384b917b43dc9ddcf3a840bb3d820e84',
  transactionHash: '0x3dd686ff899f0fd86d7f1058da955dd35065bf09709b03c0a411b10e26566872'
}
BALANCE: 0
Failed to broadcast transaction: Error: Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value
    at Object.ErrorResponse (E:\web3\backend\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\lib\errors.js:28:19)
    at E:\web3\backend\node_modules\web3-core-requestmanager\lib\index.js:300:36
    at E:\web3\backend\node_modules\web3-providers-http\lib\index.js:127:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  data: null
}
```

Could anyone please help me out with this blocker? Thanks!